# При нажатии на ссылку с logout.php, появляется ошибка "Cannot modify header information..."

Tags: php, сессия

Мне нужно сделать переадресацию на index.php после отработки logout.php.

Так выглядит logout.php:

```
require_once('header.php');
unset($_SESSION['user']);
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php');
```

В header.php написано следующее:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Разметка и т.п. Затем ниже nav и элементы списка -->
<? if(isset($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
<li><a href="/settings.php">Настройки</a></li>
<li><a href="/logout.php">Выйти</a></li>
<? else: ?>
<li><a href="/login.php">Войти</a></li>
<li><a href="/signup.php">Регистрация</a></li>
<? endif; ?>
```

Как сделать redirect, чтобы не было ошибки "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...\header.php:4) in ...\logout.php on line 4". Не пойму в чем дело...

Или вот подобная ситуация. login.php: введенные логин и пароль совпадают с данными из базы, присваиваем $_SESSION['user'], выводим сообщение "Успешная авторизация!" и вот после этого надо сделать переадресацию на index.php. Как быть? Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Перед стартом сессии есть какие-то строки? М.б. есть пробел перед открывающим пхп-тегом `<?` ? Или кодировка этого файла UTF-8 Bom.

Comment: Здесь все в порядке: и кодировка, и символов никаких нет в начале...

Answer (score 1):

Заголовки надо устанавливать **ПЕРЕД** любым выводом. В вашем случае надо будет убрать header.php (он не имеет смысла, поскольку вы выполняете редирект):

```
unset($_SESSION['user']);
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php');
```

по второму вопросу:

```
$_SESSION['user']['login_message'] = "Успешная авторизация!";
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php');
```

а уже в index.php выводите сообщение, взятое из сессии

Comment: А в index.php тоже require_once('header.php')... Может нужно убрать session_start() из 'header.php'? Тогда куда session_start() поместить, чтобы она на всех страницах была?

Comment: а в index.php пусть стоит `require_once('header.php')` ведь в нем же вы не делаете редирект.

Comment: Ошибка опять "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \header.php:2) in \login.php on line 32". Указывает как раз на header().

     $_SESSION['user'] = $result2->fetch_row();
     $_SESSION['user']['login_message'] = 'Успешная авторизация!';
     header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

Comment: Как вы фрагмент кода делаете на сером фоне в комментариях?) Все перепробовал

Comment: обратный апостроф, там , где "ё"

Comment: Убрал `session_start()` из `require_once()` и прописал во все файлы, сам же `require_once()` спустил пониже (если оставить там же, то будет ошибка). И проблема разрешилась...

Answer (score 1):

Сделай

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php');
```

Зачем там header.php нужен в логаут вообще?

По второму вопросу:
Если логин и пароль совпадают, то так как говорил коллега выше:

```
$_SESSION['user']['login_message'] = "Успешная авторизация!";
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php');
```

В файле index.php делаем вывод сообщения и сразу его удаляем:

```
echo $_SESSION['user']['login_message'];
unset($_SESSION['user']['login_message']);
```

Comment: По первой части я разобрался, убрал require_once('header.php')... Теперь по второй. Там в index.php в самом начале тоже стоит require_once('header'). Как быть?

Comment: ну и что у тебя же там header() нет, выводу и удалению сообщения из сессии это не помешает.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже говорилось в другом ответе, заголовки надо устанавливать перед выводом. Если все же нужно сделать редирект после вывода, можно использовать буферизацию. Тут самый простой способ - прописать ob_start() до вывода, и ob_end_flush() после редиректа.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
ob_start();

require_once('header.php');
unset($_SESSION['user']);
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php');

ob_end_flush();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-end-flush.php